# Excel VBA: Making Pivot Table from list of Sheet names

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

This is the start of a macro that successfully creates a pivot table based on cells from the specified sheets:

```
aray = Array("'Sheet1'!R1C5:R102C10", "'Sheet2'!R1C5:R102C10", "'Sheet3'!R1C5:R102C10", "'Sheet4'!R1C5:R102C10")

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlConsolidation, SourceData:= aray, _
    Version:= _
    xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "'[Filename.xlsm]sheet5'!R1C1", TableName:= _
    "RatingSumPiv", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

My problem is that I don't know what the sheets are named or how many there are. Their names will be in a range (a ListObject) named "UnitNumbers".

How can I automatically load the sheet names into the Array?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Sample()
Dim loSheetNames As ListObject
Dim rngCurrentSheetName As Range
Dim toprowoflo As Long
Dim lngCurrentIndex As Long

Set loSheetNames = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("listob1")
toprowoflo = loSheetNames.Range.Row
ReDim aray(loSheetNames.Rows.Count)

For Each rngCurrentSheetName In loSheetNames.Range
    lngCurrentIndex = rngCurrentSheetName.Row - toprowoflo + 1
    aray(lngCurrentIndex) = rngCurrentSheetName & "!R1C5:R102C10"
Next rngCurrentSheetName

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlConsolidation, SourceData:=aray, _
    Version:= _
    xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "'[Filename.xlsm]sheet5'!R1C1", TableName:= _
    "RatingSumPiv", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  `toprowoflo = itemslist.Range.Row` gives me an error; did you mean to say `toprowoflo = loSheetNames.Range.Row`?    Also, I get a "type mismatch" error at ReDim Preserve aray(lngCurrentIndex).

Comment: Also, since I know how many sheet names there are (its the number of rows in loSheetNames), can't I Dim the array once, outside of the loop, instead of ReDimming it repeatedly?

Comment: `ReDim aray(loSheetNames.Rows.Count)` makes the array the same length as there are rows in the list object. and yes `itemslist.Range.Row` should be `toprowoflo = loSheetNames.Range.Row` updated code now.

Comment: Thanks again.  I hate to be picky, but it has to be `ReDim aray(loSheetNames.Range.Rows.Count)` But it works!